# Detect change in associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a lead model in ruby on rails project. It is associated with lead_type model. There is a score in lead model that is calculated based on serving_factor that is present in lead_type model. If the value of serving_factor is changed the score present in lead model needs to be updated. Is there any way to do this remaining in the lead model.
Lms::Lead:

```
    belongs_to :lead_type, class_name: "Lms::LeadType", optional: true
```

The previous implementation is doing this by writing a job in LeadType model. If there is a change the job is run to update score in Lead.

Comment: What's wrong with your previous implementation? Why do you want to change it?